# How to extract file name from piped results?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, filenames

I have a text file with files following this format:

```
item1 a/b/c/d/file1.csv
item2 a/b/c/d/file2.csv
item3 a/b/c/d/file3.csv
and so on...
```

To isolate the second item in each row, I use the following:

```
cat mn_s3_files.txt | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Which yields:

```
a/b/c/d/file1.csv
a/b/c/d/file2.csv
a/b/c/d/file3.csv
and so on...
```

Now, how can I extract only the basename from the piped results?

For example:

```
cat mn_s3_files.txt | awk '{ print $1 }' | <some basename command here>
```

desired output:

```
file1
file2
file3
and so on...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use basename :) The following method worked for me on your input but might have issues with things like quoted strings etc (thanks to [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for pointing that out).

```
cat mn_s3_files.txt  | awk '{print $2}' | xargs basename
```

On Linux you can use `-d` with xargs to treat all characters literally. If you get an `extra operand` error try this:

```
cat foo | awk '{print $2}' | perl -ne '$_ =~ s[.*/(.*)][$1]; print "$_";'
```

The perl version is very brute force ie strip everything up to the last `/` on the line. You might be able to remove awk in that case.

If you want to do it in one line

```
perl -ne 's[.*/(.*)][$1]; print "$_"'  mn_s3_files.txt
```

or you could use auto split and change the separator to `/`

```
perl -F'/' -ane 'print "$F[4]"'  mn_s3_files.txt
```

**Note to readers.**

The rest of this answer is trying to answer questions from [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) in the comments. Note, his points about xargs and quotes are perfectly valid ie they can cause problems, they just didn't cause me any issue in this case.

**Pedagogy**

What's more pedagogical for someone using the command line, a pure Bash solution or a solution that uses multiple possible commands and pipes? I believe this is a subjective question and doesn't have a correct answer. I chose one solution ie one that was closely related to what I could see in the question ie the OP understands pipes and `cat` so lets use that and build on it. I chose not to go to an optimal solution because optimal could mean anything. I could write a version in C/C++ that does it as fast as hell but this seems like overkill and might not help the OP.

Some comments from Charles on this answer made me question my own understanding of *nix so I needed to address these further.

[Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) stated the following in his answer which surprised me somewhat, emphasis mine...

> You can do this all with only functionality built into bash -- anything like awk or xargs or basename is **unnecessary inefficiency**.

I decided to test this because I've not experienced this on the machines I've worked on, mostly multicore Mac and Linux. I'm assuming efficiency here means how long it would take to run the script because if applied to how long to write the command line etc that's completely dependent on the human using it and completely subjective. I benchmarked the pure bash solution ie

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r item path; do
  name=${path##*/}
  printf '%s\n' "$name"
done <mn_s3_files.txt
```

Time taken was > 17 minutes

```
real    17m34.959s
user    15m46.912s
sys     1m44.981s
```

This actually took a lot longer than I thought, in fact on the file I created I ended up killing the script twice thinking something was wrong because I wasn't expecting it to be this slow. I'm still not convinced that something isn't wrong. CPU was pegged at > 99% for the whole time.

[Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) also mentioned the following...

> It's much faster for awk to read straight from mn_s3_files.txt than to read from a FIFO that's written to by /bin/cat.

I suspect on a single core machine that this might be true but on a multicore machine it's not `much faster`. Note, `cat` is extremely efficient and will literally spend most of it's time blocked on IO because in this case. The applications on the read end of the pipe are significantly slower at reading than `cat` is at writing. I created a large file with a bunch of data similar to the OP's.

```
time cat mn_s3_files.txt  | awk '{print $2}' > /dev/null 

real    0m59.017s
user    0m57.676s
sys     0m1.833s
```

Compared to

```
time awk '{print $2}' < mn_s3_files.txt > /dev/null

real    0m59.926s
user    0m58.266s
sys     0m1.468s
```

In this case whatever comes to mind first would likely be the `fastest` and for a lot of people that's cat. While running the following command

```
time cat mn_s3_files.txt  | awk '{print $2}' | perl -ne '$_ =~ s[.*/(.*)][$1]; print "$_";' > /dev/null

real    1m6.614s
user    2m2.644s
sys 0m4.221s
```

`cat` never reached more than `1%` CPU on my machine. It's worth noting though that both `awk` and `Perl` had nearly `100%` CPU usage the whole time ie it's much less **efficient**.

Charles mentioned that `start time` was the efficiency gain he meant when he was discussing the bash script...

> Re: efficiency -- the benefit of the native while read loop is startup time, not runtime performance with long streams. You'd want to use the bash-native builtins if processing small amounts of data, and an external tool such as awk with very large amounts of data (where the time to start the external tool is overwhelmed by the time spent actually doing the processing).

this also seemed counterintuitive to me so I benchmarked bash vs awk on small files. With a file with only three lines in it the startup time had no obvious impact on the time, on multiple runs on my machine awk was actually faster **by a whole millisecond**...

```
time splitter.sh > /dev/null

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Time for awk...

```
time awk '{gsub(/.*\//, "", $2); print $2}' < mn_s3_files2.txt > /dev/null

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.006s
```

I also did it on an empty file and awk was faster. Note, at this point I realized that Charles was talking about typing it in on command line so I tried that ie

```
time while read -r item path; do name=${path##*/}; printf '%s\n' "$name"; done <mn_s3_files2.txt;
```

This was a `lot faster` than awk **(a whopping 11ms saved)** for very small files ie < 5 lines but got a lot slower very quickly ie at around 150 lines awk and bash command line was level pegging at 13ms. So to gain the performance Charles is referencing you need to type it into command line and not put it in a script or the startup costs of running the script will **completely kill performance** :).

**Fastest Typist on the planet**

Lets assume you're one of the [fastest typists on the planet](http://www.seanwrona.com/typing.php)

The fastest typists in the world are clocking in at around 50ms per letter at their best (Note I'm ignoring the fact that you may have needed to use lots of odd characters in both versions). The number of chars in the bash version is around 90 which means if you were typing at an amazing rate of 50ms per char it would take you ~4 seconds. The awk version is around 50 chars so this would take you around ~2.5 seconds to type.

So even if you're the fastest typist in the world the awk version is faster than the bash version.

[Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) in another comment said...

> I'm not sure cat mn_s3_files.txt | awk '{print $2}' | xargs basename is ever correct

The part **is ever correct** is incorrect. My original answer with xargs and the input string given worked on the following version of the mac `10.11.5` using the input from the OP with no problems.

Comment: Weird, I get the following error: `basename: extra operand`

Comment: Let me test a different method. Give me 1 minute.

Comment: At least eliminate the unnecessary `cat` calls. It's much faster for `awk` to read straight from `mn_s3_files.txt` than to read from a FIFO that's written to by `/bin/cat`. And why have both `awk` and `perl` or `awk` and `basename`? `awk` can do the work of either or both; it's a full programming language in its own right, and has complete regex support.

Comment: To do all this in one command: `awk '{gsub(/.*\//, "", $2); print $2}' <mn_s3_files.txt`

Comment: (also, using `xargs` without either `-d` or `-0` extensions is risky: The default behavior honors quotes and whitespace as syntactical, so if you have a filename with literal quotes in it -- especially an *odd* number of literal quotes, such that it's starting a quote but not closing it -- you get very unpleasant behavior).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll update the question to give some alternatives.

Comment: I'm not sure `cat mn_s3_files.txt | awk '{print $2}' | xargs basename` is *ever* correct, if the input file contains more than one entry, so I'm a little skeptical about leaving it in at all. Which is to say, adding correct alternatives is good, but leaving them under things you know to be either buggy or inefficient seems a bit suboptimal.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll update and add an explicit warning. Note, I don't want to remove it because it was accepted as is.

Comment: The consensus on meta is that editing an accepted answer is acceptable when that answer is known to be wrong. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265448/should-i-update-my-already-accepted-answer-with-improved-code and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295522/should-i-edit-my-flawed-but-accepted-answer.

Comment: Re: efficiency -- the benefit of the native `while read` loop is **startup** time, not runtime performance with long streams. You'd want to use the bash-native builtins if processing small amounts of data, and an external tool such as awk with very large amounts of data (where the time to start the external tool is overwhelmed by the time spent actually doing the processing).

Comment: ...faster by a millisecond? I find that *completely* unbelievable, if the pure-shell version was correctly implemented (zero-forking). Going to need to sit down at some point and trace through the details.

Comment: I took a very-slightly-less-cursory glance at your test procedure, and the disconnect is obvious: `time splitter.sh` is starting a **whole new shell**! That's an utterly unfair comparison, since the whole point of the native shell loop is to avoid process startup time at all (the assumption is that you already have a running shell, but you don't have a running `awk` instance, so running `awk` you pay its startup costs, but reusing your existing shell instance you pay no startup costs at all).

Comment: (...now, if the shell were real David Korn ksh93 rather than bash its post-startup runtime performance would be competitive with `awk`, but alas, ksh was licensed under restrictive commercial terms for most of its life, allowing a much slower competitor to reach ubiquity).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy... please read further into the update, I'd already covered the point about adding it to a file and the associated costs. Please update your own answer with the points you're making ie using `ksh93` in this fashion on files of this size will gain you a boost in performance of this much. I look forward to seeing your updated answer with evidence and seeing what sorts of performance gains can be had by using a different shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112564/discussion-between-harry-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[/.]' '{print $5}' file
file1
file2
file3
```

Comment: Only works if you know exactly how many `/`s there'll be. Now, maybe if you were using `$NR`...

Comment: This code-only answer would be better with some text explaining how it works and any limitations or assumptions (as pointed out by @CharlesDuffy).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all with only functionality built into bash -- anything like `awk` or `xargs` or `basename` is unnecessary inefficiency.

```
while read -r item path; do
  name=${path##*/}
  printf 'Read %q from %q\n' "$item" "$name"
done <mn_s3_files.txt
```

...yielding:

```
read item1 from file1.csv
read item2 from file2.csv
```

Obviously, to emit only `item1` and `item2`, make it just `printf '%s\n' "$name"`.